# How do you print multiple text areas in an orderly manner in Java?

Tags: java, jtextarea

Alright, so I have a dilemma. I was wondering if there is a way for me to do the following with two text areas:

I. Print the first text area, and only the first text area.
II. Upon closing the first text area, have it so the second text area appears. 
III. Do this so that both text areas do not appear at the same time.

Here is my code, sorry for all the comments, I have to teach this to fellow classmates for a project:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; //Used for events and the Action Listener

public class ActionProgram extends JFrame /*"extends JFrame" will extend the frame into the variable used to call the class*/
{
//Declare fields (Do not require public/private identification)
JTextArea area;
JLabel instructions;
JLabel question;
JLabel ask;
JButton submitt;
JScrollPane sp;

//Create a constructor to start applying these variables in the creation of the Text Area
public ActionProgram()
{
    //Create the flow layout
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //Create the text area and set how long and wide it should be. Add it to the frame
    area = new JTextArea(10,30);
    add(area);

    //Create scroll pane and add it to the frame
    sp = new JScrollPane(area);
    add(sp);

    //Set the line wrap and word wrap to true for the frame
    area.setLineWrap(true);
    area.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    //Create submitt button, and add it to the frame
    submitt = new JButton ("Submitt");
    add(submitt);

    //Create label asking user to answer the question and add it to the frame
    instructions = new JLabel("Please Answer the Following Question:");
    add(instructions);

    //Create label for the question and add it to the frame
    question = new JLabel("-----Briefly Describe how to print something in java-----");
    add(question);

    //Create label telling user what to do when finished, and add it to the frame
    ask = new JLabel("Please enter Submitt when you have finished");
    add(ask);


    //As you can tell, we do not need to put all these parts into the frame, for the class puts it all into the variable calling it

    /*In order for the program to take what the user has writen into text area and make it an input, we have to create an
    Action Listener. An Action Listener is a piece of code that will do a specific event when an action is done. In this case
    we need the action listener to respond when the user presses "Submitt". To do this, we need to create an event class*/

    //This will call the action listener class
    event action = new event();

    //This will add the action listener to the submitt button
    submitt.addActionListener(action);

}
/*The class called event will create the aciton listener. There are two different methods for the action event, the action listener
and the action performer. The action performer is the method used to create code when the action listener is activated. The listener
waits for the submitt button to be pressed, and the performer does user-inputed code when the button is pressed*/
public class event implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) //We use a nested method to create the action performer
    {
        /*The following code is what the performer will do when the listner is activated. It will get the text typed in the
        text area when the user hits the submitt button. The performer will then print the text obtained and close the text area*/
        String text = area.getText();
        System.out.println(text);

        //Use System.exit(0) to close the text area
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
            //Call the class like you usually do, and set a variable to it
            ActionProgram display = new ActionProgram();

            //display also acts as the frame of the text area since the class set it equal to the JFrame
            display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //Set the length and width of the text area in pixels
            display.setSize(500,300);

            //Set it so the text area can be seen
            display.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: *closing the first text area* what is the closing? How can I close textarea?

Comment: Do you mean setVIsible(false), so that the text area disappears?

Comment: like, close the first text area, make it go away, exit it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; //Used for events and the Action Listener

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ActionProgram extends JFrame /*
                                         * "extends JFrame" will extend the
                                         * frame into the variable used to call
                                         * the class
                                         */
{
    // Declare fields (Do not require public/private identification)
    JTextArea area;
    JLabel instructions;
    JLabel question;
    JLabel ask;
    JButton submitt;
    JScrollPane sp;
    final int TOTAL_QUESTIONS = 5; // assuming you have 5 questions
    int quizCounter = 0;
    String[] quizQuestions;

    // Create a constructor to start applying these variables in the creation of
    // the Text Area
    public ActionProgram() {
        // Create the flow layout
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // display also acts as the frame of the text area since the class set
        // it equal to the JFrame
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Set the length and width of the text area in pixels
        setSize(500, 300);

        // Create the text area and set how long and wide it should be. Add it
        // to the frame
        area = new JTextArea(10, 30);
        add(area);

        // Create scroll pane and add it to the frame
        sp = new JScrollPane(area);
        add(sp);

        // Set the line wrap and word wrap to true for the frame
        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        // Create submitt button, and add it to the frame
        submitt = new JButton("Submit");
        add(submitt);

        // Create label asking user to answer the question and add it to the
        // frame
        instructions = new JLabel("Please Answer the Following Question:");
        add(instructions);

        // Create label for the question and add it to the frame
        quizQuestions = questions();

        question = new JLabel(quizQuestions[quizCounter]);
        add(question);

        // Create label telling user what to do when finished, and add it to the
        // frame
        ask = new JLabel("Please enter Submit when you have finished");
        add(ask);

        // As you can tell, we do not need to put all these parts into the
        // frame, for the class puts it all into the variable calling it

        /*
         * In order for the program to take what the user has writen into text
         * area and make it an input, we have to create an Action Listener. An
         * Action Listener is a piece of code that will do a specific event when
         * an action is done. In this case we need the action listener to
         * respond when the user presses "Submitt". To do this, we need to
         * create an event class
         */

        // This will call the action listener class
        event action = new event();

        // This will add the action listener to the submitt button
        submitt.addActionListener(action);

    }


    /*
     * The class called event will create the aciton listener. There are two
     * different methods for the action event, the action listener and the
     * action performer. The action performer is the method used to create code
     * when the action listener is activated. The listener waits for the submitt
     * button to be pressed, and the performer does user-inputed code when the
     * button is pressed
     */
    public class event implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) // We use a nested method to
                                                    // create the action
                                                    // performer
        {
            /*
             * The following code is what the performer will do when the listner
             * is activated. It will get the text typed in the text area when
             * the user hits the submitt button. The performer will then print
             * the text obtained and close the text area
             */
            if (e.getSource() == submitt) {
                String text = area.getText();
                System.out.println(text);
                dispose();

                // increment the amount of times questions were asked - i.e. the frame opened
                quizCounter++;

                if (quizCounter < TOTAL_QUESTIONS ) {
                    quizQuestions = questions();
                    area.setText("");
                    question.setText(quizQuestions[quizCounter]);
                    setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }       
        }
    }

    public String[] questions() {

        String[] newQuestion = new String[TOTAL_QUESTIONS];
        switch(quizCounter) {
        case 0:
            newQuestion[0] = "-----Briefly Describe how to print something in java-----";
            break;
        case 1:
            newQuestion[1] = "----- Question 2 -------";
            break;
        case 2:
            newQuestion[2] = "Question 3";
            break;
        case 3:
            newQuestion[3] = "Question 4";
            break;
        case 4:
            newQuestion[4] = "Question 5";
            break;
        }

        return newQuestion;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Call the class like you usually do, and set a variable to it
        ActionProgram display = new ActionProgram();

        // Set it so the text area can be seen
        display.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

The answer is laid out on the assumption that you are going to ask 5 questions. Please change the quantity for the `TOTAL_QUESTIONS` variable to fit with your criteria. Also, don't forget to modify the `questions()` method body.

It is a good practice to set up all your actions for the `JFrame` in the construction, rather than in the `main`. I have amended the code accordingly. Also, it is a good habit to use `SwingUtilities` to run swing applications.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        new ActionProgram().setVisible(true);

    }
});
```

If you have any queries, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can not close a JTextArea, until unless you are wrapping the JTextArea in a JScrollPane and then adding the JScrollPan to JPanel.

If you are able to perform all these steps then you can use  `FocusListener` 
which is used to shift the focus from one component to another.

You can read more about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html).